# Regular Expression allow null or 1 to 9 digit

Tags: angularjs, regex

I have tried to validate my input quantity field by using pattern attribute. But my regular expression not working. Please check

```
^(?:[1-9]\d*|)$
```

Please anyone help me. My input field should accept null or 1 to 9 digit. Not accept 0 or any letter and symbol.

AngulrJS code:

```
<input class="form-control" name="quantity" ng-model="quoteList.quantity" placeholder="Quantity" required="" min="1" ng-pattern="/^(?:[1-9]\d*|)$/">
<div ng-show="userForm.$submitted || userForm.quantity.$touched">
    <span ng-show="userForm.quantity.$error.pattern" class="text-danger">Not valid number!</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you want your regex to match a _single_ number only, or multiple numbers?

Comment: Multiple number

Comment: you want a number that has 1 to 9 **digits**, not a number that only contains the digits 1-9 (i.e. excluding 0)

Comment: Your original `^(?:[1-9]\d*|)$` is working - it does not allow `01`. *Please specify what problem you have with the current solution*. "not working" is not the right problem description, since it is matching `10` and does not match `01`, and also matches an empty string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to match multiple numbers `1-9` use:

```
^[1-9]*$
```

This regex is as good as it gets with regard to checking for `NULL` values.  If you want to also allow nulls, then you should include this logic explicitly in your controller, i.e.

```
form.input.$valid || quoteList.quantity === null
```

**Update:**

It appears that what you really wanted to ask is how to validate a number which *begins* with `1-9`, but then can be followed by *any* digit.  If so, then try this regex:

```
^[1-9][0-9]*$
```

Again, you can check in your controller for null values and also allow them too.

Comment: Yes it does, at least in some engines.  What tool/language are you using?

Comment: I am using AngularJS

Comment: Updated my question. Please check

Comment: Thank you for your answering :)

Comment: Sorry for delay. I am getting another problem if I am using your expression. all are working fine except 0. Ex: 10, 101, 100 etc. Please help me.

Comment: You should open a new question.  It sounds like you want to _allow_ zero so long as it is not the first digit.  Is that correct?  This is not at all what your original question implied though.

Comment: This is my related question. allow 1 to 9 digit. But 10, 100 not working. Please updated your answer.

Comment: @Chinmay235 OK I updated my answer again.  I hope this meets your requirements.

Comment: I am asking another question.

Comment: See - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40377762/regular-expression-allow-zero-so-long-as-it-is-not-the-first-digit

Comment: Another question requires an answer `^(?:[1-9]\d*|)$` - the one you are actually using.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Careful: regex in Angular is a bit tricky and that might not work.  Rather, use the regex pattern for positive matches and then allow nulls programatically by checking in the controller.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: How tricky is the *regex* in angular? What do you mean by "tricky"? There is only one tricky thing about how angular processes the input passed to the regex, but you have not even mentioned that in your answer.

Answer (score 2):

You may check by yourself:

https://regex101.com^(?:[1-9]\d*|)$

Answer (score 0):

```
^(?:[1-9]*)$
```

Should be enough.

Comment: You don't need the parentheses now :-)

Comment: Can you elaborate more on why it qualifies as a correct answer?

Comment: It's a simple regex I don't think there's a need for elaboration but if you still want to learn the basics  [basics here](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/back-to-basics-regular-expressions)