# Regular expression allow zero so long as it is not the first digit

Tags: regex, numbers

Yesterday I was posting one question here **[Regular Expression allow null or 1 to 9 digit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40354842/regular-expression-allow-null-or-1-to-9-digit/40354899)** This was working fine after that I saw in my quantity field not taking 10, 100, 1002 etc. value. because these values also present 0(zero) digit. So Please help me.

Comment: Try `^[^0]\d*$` and `^[1-9][0-9]*$`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I actually gave Tushar's regex in the original question.  I directed him to open because he change would have invalidated all 3 original answers and that isn't nice.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: OP wrote *I am getting another problem if I am using your expression.* - why open a new question? Provide working answers in the original question after it is made clear. Right now, it is not.

Answer (score 3):

If you want null or a number that *starts* from `[1-9]` but can *contain* `[0-9]`, the pattern is

```
 (^[1-9][0-9]*$)|(^$)
```

please, notice that a *single zero* is not allowed: `0` *doesn't match*. In case you want to match it as well (you want a *empty string*, *zero* - `0` or a *number* which must start from `[1-9]` and can contain `[0-9]`)

```
 (^[1-9][0-9]*$)|(^0?$)
```

Comment: OP's [`^(?:[1-9]\d*|)$`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40354842/regular-expression-allow-null-or-1-to-9-digit/40354899) is the same in functionality.

Answer (score 1):

I would do with this expression:

```
(^[1-9][0-9]*$)|(^$)
```

or even shorter using \d which means [0-9]:

```
    (^[1-9]\d*$)|(^$)
```

Comment: @DmitryBychenko in which case now I just happen to have the same solution than you. +1 for you ;-)